Tilix terminal emulator won't open at default profile's default dimensions (windows size)
Symptom
In Tilix, I have a default profile where window size is set to 120 columns and 34 lines. However, when I open Tilix, it always open at 86 columns and 18 lines, as follows:
$ tput lines && tput cols

18
86

It always opens at this size however I change my default profile settings. This is not the smallest window either, because after it opens I can resize the window to become even smaller than this.
I could recall that when I first installed Tilix, it was working fine. Suddenly starting one day (not sure if it was because of a system update or not), it behaved like mentioned above and never became normal again.
I have been using Tilix for some time, this is the first time I see this happening. This is also the first desktop setup that uses KDE as the desktop so I suspect if this has anything to do with KDE.
Additional info

In Tilix, "save and restore window state" is unchecked.
Changing to other profiles for default profile does not help either.
Konsole seems to be able to open at 120 columns and 34 lines without any issue.
Unlike someone who complained that all windows open very small, for me this seems to only happen to Tilix.
I found some older posts that suggest to check some KDE-owned window state restoration feature, but I did not find any relevant option in the right-click menu of the Tilix title bar.

Software version
Tilix

Tilix: 1.9.6

About system: Linux and KDE

Operating System: EndeavourOS
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.1
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.3.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.6.36-1-lts (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 2 × Intel® Celeron® N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz
Memory: 3.7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600
Manufacturer: Google
Product Name: Blorb
System Version: rev5

